# Upgrade angular 2 dependencies inside angular2-cli project

Tags: javascript, angular, npm, angular2-cli

After playing around with angular2 and following angular2 guide in thier website I tryied to move to angular2-cli but angular2-cli project doesnt have the most updated dependencies so the compiler give me some errors about some commands in the code.

I want to upgrade all of the dependencies like core,**router** and more.
the most updated router need the most updated core but when I try to do: npm install core -g, i get a lots of errors.

What is the best and fast way to upgrade all the exsisting dependencies?

Here are the package.json of angular-cli and angular website:

**angular2-cli - orginial package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "angular2-projects",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "start": "ng serve",
    "postinstall": "typings install",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.8",
    "es6-shim": "0.35.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "systemjs": "0.19.26",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.9",
    "codelyzer": "0.0.20",
    "ember-cli-inject-live-reload": "1.4.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.4.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "0.13.22",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.2.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "0.3.8",
    "protractor": "3.3.0",
    "ts-node": "0.5.5",
    "tslint": "3.11.0",
    "typescript": "1.8.10",
    "typings": "0.8.1"
  }
}
```

**most updated angular2 dependencies from angular2 website:**

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/router-deprecated": "2.0.0-rc.2",
    "@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0-rc.4",
    "core-js": "^2.4.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.6",
    "zone.js": "0.6.12",
    "angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.14",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "concurrently": "^2.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.0"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you've updated your dependencies in the packages.json, delete the node_modules directory, and then run "npm install." That will install all the packages from your configuration.

Comment: There is no need to delete ` node_modules` you can run `npm i --save`

Comment: If you don't delete "node_modules,"  all the old packages are left in there and things can get really confusing.

Answer (score 1):

I'm unsure if the question has been answered but to give a direct answer, the easiest and fastest way to upgrade all **existing** dependencies in a `package.json` file is to go into the folder that houses said file (or any child thereof) and run the following:

```
npm update
```

That will update all dependencies (dev included) to the latest supported versions inside your `package.json` and install them for you, ready to use. Doing it this way also has the added benefit of meaning that if there are versions of libraries that don't work well together, the update process will steer clear of them.

You can even run `npm outdated` after the update to see what libraries you have, what you need and if there are any updates on the NPM registry.